# How to update sqlite from another thread

Tags: android, multithreading

i m building an android apps where i need to update an already created sqlite database from another runnable thread using extended sqliteopenhelper class continuously. I've tried so many but not succeeded so far. Apps not displaying any error but database not updating. I do not want to use asynctask or handler because of screen frozen issues. Plz help me.

Comment: Even though the app doesn't crash, error messages may be shown in logcat output. check and post that for more details

Comment: If you use an AsyncTask your screen won't freeze unless you make it freeze or wait for a result with a dialog for example. Thats why it is called AsyncTask, its runs asynchronously

Comment: Are you by any chance updating the UI from that "another thread"?

Comment: @Ricardo Barroca, thank for ur suggestion, but its very much diificult to update sqlite from asynctask even after using of sqliteopenhelper. Thats why i was trying to use thread in backgroung. Plz enlight me in this issue